# useEffect hook for login via local storage

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-router

I'm creating a React + Next.js app with authorisation and I need to get token from local storage. If I do this without useEffect, there is an error of undefined localstorage, but with use effect my redirects don't work, maybe you know where am I wrong?

```
"use client";
//modules
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

//styles
import styles from "./page.module.sass";

//components
import NewCV from "./components/newCv";
import Cvs from "./components/cvs";
import PersonalInfo from "./components/personalInfo";
import LayoutPicker from "./components/LayoutPicker";

//helpers
import { vaildToken } from "@/app/authorization";

export default function MyPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [catType, setCatType] = useState(0);
  const cat = (type) => setCatType(type);

  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);
  const [role, setRole] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const res = vaildToken(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    setValid(res[0]);
    setRole(res[1]);

    if (valid !== true && role !== "USER") {
      router.push("/login");
    }
  }, [valid, role]);

  console.log(valid, role)

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      {valid !== true && role !== "USER" ? (
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <LayoutPicker cat={cat} />
          {catType == 1 ? <Cvs /> : catType == 2 ? <NewCV /> : <PersonalInfo />}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: `[valid, role]` are dependencies of the effect and you also set them in the effect which is a red flag as it may lead to the effect entering an infinite loop.  It's also not clear what their purpose is at all

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition as follows cause you won't get the state value immediately.

```
if (res[0] !== true && res[1] !== "USER") {
  router.push("/login");
}
```

Hope, it'll work.